# how to add bootstrap template to ASP.net MVC 2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

layout file is not there how to add bootstrap template in MVC 2 project . And there is no template in add item to add a .cshtml file

Comment: It is really time to upgrade frameworks...